# Is it possible to match many to many rows with random order?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I need to compare two tables with 2 the same columns ( code, text). I need to check that all from table2 is in table1. Problem is for every codes is 10-20 rows with same CODE number with different value( random order) in second column and vlookup doesnt work, can some1 help me how to lookup it? Below sample with 1 code:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Concatenate `CODE` and `Text` column in both table and apply the vlookup.

Comment: got it, thanks a lot